# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .tj_row_1,.tj_row_2,.tj_row_3, at Function.Sizzle.error

Tags: jquery, grid, slider

I use jquery plugin to display slider grid when i use jquery 1.6 it work fine when i change to jquery 2.4.1 it show this error :

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:.tj_row_1,.tj_row_2,.tj_row_3, at Function.Sizzle.error

after search i found that error caused by this part of code :

```
    pagination  : function( $wrapper, dir, opts ) {
                    var config = $wrapper.data('config');

                    if( ( dir === 1 && config.currentRow + opts.rows > config.totalRows ) ||
                        ( dir === -1 && config.currentRow - 1 <= 0 )
                    ) {
                        $wrapper.data( 'anim', false );
                        return false;
                    }

                    var movingRows  = '';

                    for( var i = 0; i <= opts.rows; ++i ) {
                        ( dir === 1 )
                            ? movingRows += ".tj_row_" + (config.currentRow + i) + ","
                            : movingRows += ".tj_row_" + (config.currentRow + (i - 1)) + ",";
                    }

                    var seq_t   = opts.type.factor,
                        $elements;

                    var dircond = 1;
                    if( opts.type.reverse ) dircond = -1;
                    if( dir === dircond ) {
                        $elements = $wrapper.children(movingRows);
                    }else {
                        $elements = $wrapper.children(movingRows).reverse();
                    }
                    var total_elems = $elements.length,
                        cnt         = 0;

                    $elements.each(function(i) {
                        var $el         = $(this),
                            row         = $el.attr("class"),
                            animParam   = {},

                            currentRow  = config.currentRow;

                        setTimeout(function() {
// if first row fade out
// if last row fade in
// for all the rows move them up / down
                            if( dir === 1 ) {
                                if(  row === "tj_row_" + (currentRow) ) {
                                    animParam.opacity   = 0;
                                }
                                else if( row === "tj_row_" + (currentRow + opts.rows) ) {
                                    animParam.opacity   = 1;
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                if(  row === "tj_row_" + (currentRow - 1) ) {
                                    animParam.opacity   = 1;
                                }
                                else if( row === "tj_row_" + (currentRow + opts.rows - 1) ) {
                                    animParam.opacity   = 0;
                                }
                            }

                            $el.show();

                            (dir === 1)
                                ? animParam.top = $el.position().top - $el.height() + 'px'
                                : animParam.top = $el.position().top + $el.height() + 'px'

                            $el.stop().animate(animParam, opts.type.speed, opts.type.easing, function() {
                                if( parseInt( animParam.top ) < 0 || parseInt( animParam.top ) > $el.height() * (opts.rows - 1) )
                                    $el.hide();

                                ++cnt;
                                if( cnt === total_elems ) {
                                    $wrapper.data( 'anim', false );
                                }
                            });
                        }, seq_t + i * seq_t);
                    });

                    (dir === 1) ? config.currentRow += 1 : config.currentRow -= 1;

                    $wrapper.data('config', config);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the trailing `,` on the `movingRows` selector string.

To fix this you would be better to create the selectors in an array and then `join()` them before use, something like this:

```js
var config = { currentRow: 1 }
var opts = { rows: 5 }
var dir = 1;

var classes = [];
for (var i = 0; i < opts.rows; i++) {
  var suffix = config.currentRow + (dir == 1 ? i : i - 1);
  classes.push('.tj_row_' + suffix);
}

var movingRows = classes.join(',');
console.log(movingRows);
```

Comment: the error has changed to :Uncaught TypeError: opts.rows.map is not a function
    at Object.pagination (jquery.gridnav.js:345)
    at HTMLSpanElement.<anonymous> (jquery.gridnav.js:710)
    at HTMLSpanElement.dispatch (jquery-2.1.4.js:4435)
    at HTMLSpanElement.elemData.handle (jquery-2.1.4.js:4121)

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake. I thought `opts.rows` was an array. I updated the answer for you

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in the value passed here :

```
( dir === 1 )? $currentRowElements = $wrapper.children(currentRows)
: $currentRowElements = $wrapper.children(currentRows).reverse();
```

the currentRows="string of value"=.tj_row_1,.tj_row_2,.tj_row_3,.tj_row_4,.tj_row_5

i convert the string to array then i get the next value of array:

```
     pagination : function( $wrapper, dir, opts ) {
                        var config = $wrapper.data('config');

                        if( ( dir === 1 && config.currentRow + opts.rows > config.totalRows ) ||
                            ( dir === -1 && config.currentRow - 1 <= 0 )
                        ) {
                            $wrapper.data( 'anim', false );
                            return false;
                        }

                        var movingRows  = '';

                        for( var i = 0; i <= opts.rows; ++i ) {
                            ( dir === 1 )
                                ? movingRows += '.tj_row_' + (config.currentRow + i) + ','
                                : movingRows += '.tj_row_' + (config.currentRow + (i - 1)) + ',';
                        }
                        //var movingRows = opts.rows.map(function(v, i) {
                        //    var suffix = config.currentRow + (dir == 1 ? i : i - 1);
                        //    return '.tj_row_' + suffix;
                        //}).join(',');

                        var seq_t   = opts.type.factor,
                            $elements;

                        var dircond = 1;
                        if( opts.type.reverse ) dircond = -1;
//convert to array
                        arr = movingRows.split(',');
//function to get the next value of array
                        function nextSlide(num) {
                            var p=[];
                            return p[($.inArray(num, p) + 1) % p.length];
                        }
                        ( dir === dircond )
                            ? $elements = $wrapper.children(nextSlide(arr))
                            : $elements = $wrapper.children(nextSlide(arr)).reverse();

                        var total_elems = $elements.length,
                            cnt         = 0;

                        $elements.each(function(i) {
                            var $el         = $(this),
                                row         = $el.attr('class'),
                                animParam   = {},

                                currentRow  = config.currentRow;

                            setTimeout(function() {
                                // if first row fade out
                                // if last row fade in
                                // for all the rows move them up / down
                                if( dir === 1 ) {
                                    if(  row === 'tj_row_' + (currentRow) ) {
                                        animParam.opacity   = 0;
                                    }
                                    else if( row === 'tj_row_' + (currentRow + opts.rows) ) {
                                        animParam.opacity   = 1;
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    if(  row === 'tj_row_' + (currentRow - 1) ) {
                                        animParam.opacity   = 1;
                                    }
                                    else if( row === 'tj_row_' + (currentRow + opts.rows - 1) ) {
                                        animParam.opacity   = 0;
                                    }
                                }

                                $el.show();

                                (dir === 1)
                                    ? animParam.top = $el.position().top - $el.height() + 'px'
                                    : animParam.top = $el.position().top + $el.height() + 'px'

                                $el.stop().animate(animParam, opts.type.speed, opts.type.easing, function() {
                                    if( parseInt( animParam.top ) < 0 || parseInt( animParam.top ) > $el.height() * (opts.rows - 1) )
                                        $el.hide();

                                    ++cnt;
                                    if( cnt === total_elems ) {
                                        $wrapper.data( 'anim', false );
                                    }
                                });
                            }, seq_t + i * seq_t);
                        });

                        (dir === 1) ? config.currentRow += 1 : config.currentRow -= 1;

                        $wrapper.data('config', config);
                    }
```